# Multidimensional LSTM

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I'm having a problem to make at least one functional machine learning model, the examples I found all over the network are either off topic or good but incomplete (missing dataset, explanations...).
The closest example related to my problem is [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/sequence-to-sequence-classification-using-deep-learning.html).
I'm trying to create a model based on accelerometer & gyroscope sensor, each one has its own 3 axis, for example if I lift the sensor parallel to the gravity then return it back to his initial position, then I should have a table like this.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct9bj.png)
Now this whole table correspond to one movement which I call it "Fade_away", and the duration for this same movement is variable.
I have only two main questions:

1. In which format I need to save my dataset, because I don't think an array could arrange this kind of data?
2. How can I implement a simple model at least with one hidden layer?

To make it easier, let's say that I have 3 outputs, "Fade_away", "Punch" and "Rainbow".

Comment: probably you can try [ConvLSTM2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D).

Comment: Thank you for replying but it's a little bit confusing, there are so many information, is there an example similar to what I'm looking for?